# Print list of filenames except for the ones specified in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder ***test*** with

```
file1.txt
file2.wav
file3.txt
file4.py
```

I have a ***dont_include.txt*** file outside the ***test*** folder with contents

```
file1.txt
file4.py
```

How to print all the filenames in the ***test*** folder except for the ones listed in ***dont_include.txt***

Desired output:

```
file2.wav
file3.txt
```

Comment: I could print the file names in the folder with `find ./  -printf "%f\n"`. I can do it using a python script but I am looking for some bash command

Comment: `printf '%s\n' * | grep -vFf dont_include.txt` from inside `test` folder

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep:

```
ls test | grep -xvFf dont_include.txt -
```

- `-f` means the list of patterns is taken from file, dont_include.txt in this case
- `-F` means the patterns are interpreted as literal strings rather than regular expressions, so a.txt won't match abtxt
- `-x` matches only whole lines, i.e. `other_file.txt` won't be matched by `file.txt`
- `-v` means we want to print the *non-matching* lines
- `-` (optional) means the list we're filtering is the standard intput, i.e. the output of `ls` in this case.

It doesn't work for files with newlines in their names (but storing them in a file one per line is already wrong anyway).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanations as well. I should read grep documentation

Comment: It would be better to add `-x` (match whole lines) to the `grep` options.  That would prevent files like `other_file1.txt` being excluded.